# PHP file/class name collision

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have a files structure like this:

```
Class (folder):
 - User.php
 - Rule.php
Scripts (folder):
 - user.php (in lowercase)
 - otherscript.php

index.php
```

### Rule class (Class/Rule.php):

```
namespace My\Namespace;
require_once 'Gender.php';
require_once 'User.php';

class Rule
{
...
```

### User class (Class/User.php):

```
namespace My\Namespace;
require_once 'Gender.php';
class User {
...
```

In the Rule class I use a 'require_once' that includes the User class (require_once 'User.php'), the problem is that when I include de Rule class in 'otherscript.php' it includes me both (script/user.php and class/User.php). How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either `require_once` the element relative to itself rather the to whatever the current working dir may be:

```
   require_once __DIR__.'/Gender.php';
   require_once __DIR__.'/User.php';
```

... but it would be even better to just define an autoloader (use the SPL autoloader rather then the old `__autoload` function) which takes care of that for you, removing the need for most include/require statements for classes.

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken I'll try using __DIR__ and then I will learn how to use the SPL autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

I usually include the full path from my project root upwards to avoid this. Why not just do:

```
require_once('Class/User.php');
```

This is much more specific and gets around the guess work that PHP needs to do to figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you dont have any **class collisions within some folders**, you can use this tool: https://github.com/shipmonk-rnd/name-collision-detector (usable in CI)

It is used by PHPStan itself and analyses thousands of files in few seconds.

```
$ composer require --dev shipmonk/name-collision-detector
$ vendor/bin/detect-collisions src tests

My\Namespace\User is defined 2 times:
 > /src/Entity/User.php
 > /tests/Samples/User.php
```